# ThreeJS and VR (WebXR) debugging

Tags: three.js, webvr, webxr, oculusquest

I have Oculus Quest and I want to support VR mode in my THREEJS app. The question is: how to debug this mode (controls etc.)? Oculus and Firefox Reality browsers don't have chrome devtools. I've tried WebVR and WebXR emulation plugins. WebXR emulation works in Firefox Nightly (dev) build only. But is doesn't work in chromium/chrome canary (special flags are enabled). 
[image]
How can I emulate webxr in chrome?
Is it possible to use real headset but debug in desktop?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get WebXR emilation working in chrome canary build by restoring XR-flags to defaults. Only WebVR flag should be enabled.
For debugging I use Firefox (desktop) remote debugging with Firefox Reality (headset connected via USB adb drivers). It seems that chrome remote debugging can do it as well.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Current release of oculus browser has webxr enabled by default.  Chrome devtools work very well.  If you want to troubleshoot without using headset, immersive web extension for chrome also let's you emulate headset/controller placement as well and button/touch events.